# Code crashes on realloc(), and I can't figure out why, segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-arrays

I am trying to write a program that reads input and prints it with 60 characters each line, with a pointer to store the characters.
And I always get segmentation fault when entering a lot of characters, and I think the realloc() cause it but I can't figure out why.

This is my code (a little long but if someone can help me I will be thankful):
Ignore the empty functions.

```
int main() {
    int opt;
    char *p;
    int checkRead = -1;
    
    
    p = (char*) calloc(60,1);
    
    scanf("%d",&opt);
    
    checkRead = readText(opt,p);
    if (!checkRead) {
        
}

int readText(int opt, char *p) {
    switch(opt) {
        case dynamicList:
             return dynamicReadText(p);
    return 1;
}

int dynamicReadText(char *p) {
    register int i;
    int ch;
    char *checker = NULL;
    fflush(stdin);
    
    for (i = 0; (ch = getchar()) != EOF; i++) {
        if (i >= 60 && i % 60 == 0) {
            checker = (char*)realloc(p,i+60);
            if (!*(checker)) {
                return 0;
            }
            p = checker;
            free(checker);
            checker = NULL;
            *(p+i) = '\n';
            i++;
        }
        if (ch == '\n') {
            i--;
        }
        else {
            *(p+i) = ch;
        }
    }
    *(p+i) = '\0';
    
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Use after free is undefined behavior.

Comment: You shouldn't call `free` after `realloc`. `realloc` does that *when needed*. You should free it once, when you're done using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems are numerous.

---

```c
checker = (char*)realloc(p,i+60);
if (!*(checker))
```

should be

```c
checker = (char*)realloc(p,i+60);
if (!checker)
```

You want to check if the value returned by `realloc` is `NULL`. You are instead checking if the first character of the memory block is zero.

---

This second problem is the probably the one leading to the SIGSEGV.

Select lines of your code:

```c
char *checker = NULL;
checker = (char*)realloc(p,i+60);  // Allocates a memory block.
p = checker;                       // Both p and checker points to this block.
free(checker);                     // The block is freed.
*(p+i) = '\n';                     // XXX Derefs a pointer pointing to freed memory.
```

---

Finally, you are changing the `dynamicReadText`'s `p` with the expectancy that this will change the `p` in `readText`. Similarly, you expect that changing `readText`'s `p` will change `main`'s. But these are entirely different variables. C always passes by value.

---

Well, I said finally, but only in the sense that this is the extent of what this answer covers. I haven't established that there are no other problems.

All together, your code should look something like this:

```c
int f(char **p_ptr) {
   ...

   while (...) {
      ...

      char* tmp = realloc(*p_ptr, ...);
      if (!tmp) {
         ...
      }

      *p_ptr = tmp;

      ...
   }

   ...
}

int main(void) {
   char *p = NULL;
   f(&p);

   ...

   free(p);
}
```

Comment: Yep, use after `free()` will get you every time... `:)`

Comment: Thank you so much!
You really saved me with this, now it works.
Thanks! :)